# Bash en WSL no reconoce comando?

Tags: bash, jupyter, wsl

- Abro Bash y escribo jupyter notebook  > command not found
- Hago lo    mismo en Cmd y sí funciona (abre una Jupyter Notebook)
- Tengo agregado a mi PATH todo    lo    necesario para que abra. Hay
  algún problema con el Windows    Subsystem    for Linux?
- Por qué no    reconoce el comando aún habiéndolo agregado a mi PATH?

[image: El path existe, y funciona con Cmd pero no con bash de wsl]

Comment: en lugar de publicar imágenes, comparte en texto para que se vea mejor

Comment: Hola diego, ¿te valió la respuesta? ¿Necesitas algo más?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `WSL` no interpreta lo mismo que el `CMD`, para eso tienes que ejecutarlo llamando al `.exe` de `CMD`.

Por ejemplo en mi caso, que tengo todo en `C:\`, para cambiar la contraseña de un usuario es así:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c new user prueba 123456
```

Por lo que en tu caso diría que es así:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c jupyter notebook
```

Prueba y me comentas.

Y para PowerShell tengo hay poner por delante `powershell` eso lo tiene bastante bien integrado, al menos, en las últimas versiones.

Comment: Lo hice y funcionó! Pero cómo puedo evitar hacer eso? Porque de otra forma, activar el WSL y usar bash realmente no está sirviendo :( Quisiera usar bash para todos mis desarrollos. Ojo: puedo estar hablando rocas, ya que recién comienzo en este mundo.

Comment: Ahora intenté directamente en bash escribiendo jupyter-notebook.exe y funcionó perfectamente, por qué será?

Comment: No es lo mismo escribir `jupyter notebook` que `jupyter-notebook.exe`. El segundo comando hace referencia a un `*.exe` que se puede interpretar por la extensión y que `WSL` directamente lo ejecute con `CMD`. El primero comando lo da como uno de la `shell` directamente y ahí no existe. No se si me explico.

Comment: @DiegoSalgadoQuintanilla Las preguntas que haces tienen respuesta en el foro en con los tags "bash" y "linux". Todo lo que preguntas esta en función del concepto de la variable de entorno `$PATH`

Comment: @Sakrow pero entonces qué podría hacer para que funcione directamente desde bash y no tener que abrir cmd?

Comment: En ese caso lo mejor seria crearte un alias dentro de la shell (https://shapeshed.com/unix-alias/). Pero eso ya corresponde a otra pregunta.